# p adic valuation strong triangle inequality

Tags: real-analysis, p-adic-number-theory

I dont understand of the proof on Bachman's book ''Introduction to p-adic numbers and valuation theory''. (Page 3)

if $\mid x \mid_p \leq 1$ then $\mid 1+x \mid_p \leq 1.$

Comment: Could tell us where in the proof you find it hard to follow? (Also, you don't seem to have actually asked a question).

Comment: the part is if $\mid x \mid_p \leq 1$ then we can write $x=\frac{c}{d}$ where $(c,d)=1$ and p does not divide d. Then $1+x=1+\frac{c}{d}=\frac{c+d}{d}$ and $1+x$ also has a denominator prime to p; whence $\mid 1+x \mid_p \leq 1.$ Why is it sufficient to have a denominator prime to p ?

Comment: The idea here is that $v_p(d)=0$ since it is relatively prime to $p$. How do you define the metric with respect to the valuation? Now $c,d$ are integers, and hence $v_p(c+d)\geq 0$. Can you conclude then that $v_p(\frac{c+d}{d})\geq 0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does the triangle inequality tell you? The fact that $|x|_p\leq 1$ tells you that $v_p(x)\geq 0$. Then $v_p(1)=0 (Why?)$. We also know that $v_p(a+x)\geq \min \{v_p(a), v_p(x)\}$. Can you conclude the result from this?

Comment: especially i need to learn that proof i have written.